# obtaining Current directory in VC++ forms

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I am working on a vc++ forms code. I need to get the current directory to open the help form of the project. While I tried all the code which I could find on internet everything as the same problem. I am posting one of the code below. The output of the code is true or false it is not returning the string which as a current directory value.

TCHAR pwd[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, pwd);
MessageBox::Show(Convert::ToString(&pwd), "My Application", MessageBoxButtons::OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon::Asterisk);

please help me out how to know the current directory in VC++ forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the address of the pointer to Convert::ToString().  pwd is an array and using the variable name without an array subscript automatically decays to a pointer.  You want to use either

```
Convert::ToString(pwd)
```

or

```
Convert::ToString(&pwd[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using C++/CLI. In that case, you should use .NET functions, whenevver possible... so instead of "GetCurrentDirectory" you should use the property [`System::Environment::CurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx)!

Alternatively you should disable /clr (.NET) support and only use native functions!

If you really want to mix native and managed code, you should use the constructor for `String` to convert from TCHAR:

```
String^ str = gcnew String(pwd);
```